# React component is making infinite API calls

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created an `API` endpoint that gives product title back when the user tries to search. Now on the frontend side, I will make an API call to that endpoint when enters some keystrokes on the input field. So I have written that component in `React` as a class-based component. It works fine. But now I wanted to convert that component in the newer version of `React` by using `React` hooks.

My **class-based** implementation works fine. What I did is when the user enters some keystrokes. I `debounce` i.e. delays the execution of the passed function as an argument. The function is `handleSearchChange()` which takes value from the field and checks if `value` string is greater than 1 character then after the specified delay makes an API call which in response gives back some results.

The server filter the results from the following data:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Cummings - Nikolaus",
    "description": "Assimilated encompassing hierarchy",
    "image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/michalhron/128.jpg",
    "price": "$20.43"
  },
  {
    "title": "Batz, Kiehn and Schneider",
    "description": "Public-key zero tolerance portal",
    "image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/attacks/128.jpg",
    "price": "$58.97"
  },
  {
    "title": "Borer, Bartell and Weber",
    "description": "Programmable motivating system engine",
    "image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/craighenneberry/128.jpg",
    "price": "$54.51"
  },
  {
    "title": "Brekke, Mraz and Wyman",
    "description": "Enhanced interactive website",
    "image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/vaughanmoffitt/128.jpg",
    "price": "$53.28"
  },
  {
    "title": "Willms and Sons",
    "description": "Compatible next generation superstructure",
    "image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/madcampos/128.jpg",
    "price": "$49.82"
  }
]
```

Class-based implementation:

```
//#region Global imports
import React, { Component, ReactElement } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';
//#endregion Global imports


//#region Types
type Data = object;

type StateType = {
    isLoading: boolean;
    results: Data[];
    value: string | undefined;
}
//#endregion Types

//#region Component
const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    results: [],
    value: '',
};

export class SearchInputV1 extends Component<{}, StateType> {

    // React component using ES6 classes no longer autobind `this` to non React methods.
    constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
        super(props);
        this.state = initialState;
        this.getSearchResults = this.getSearchResults.bind(this);
        this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
    }

    // Function to make an API call
    async getSearchResults() {
        try {
            const { value } = this.state;
            const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/products?q=${value}`);
            this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: false, results: data }));
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    handleSearchChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {

        const { target } = event;

        const val = target.value;
        this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: true, value: val }));
        console.log('Method debounce : Type value is : ', val);
        setTimeout(() => {
            const { value } = this.state;
            if (typeof value === 'string' && value.length < 1) {
                return this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, ...initialState }));
            }
              // Makes an API call              
              this.getSearchResults();
        }, 300);
    };


    render(): ReactElement<any> {
        const { value, results } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="search"/>
                <input type="text" value={value} id="search" name="query"
                       onChange={_.debounce(this.handleSearchChange, 500, { leading: true })}/>

                <div>
                    {results.map((element, index) => {
                        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
                        // @ts-ignore
                        return <p key={index}>{element.title}</p>;
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}


//#endregion Component
```

Now here is the problem, In my `React` hook implementation when I make an `API` call then it would never stop it is making an infinite API calls to the server.

**What I'm doing wrong and How to fix it?**

Hooks implementaion:

```
//#region Global imports
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';
//#endregion Global imports


//#region Types
type Data = object;

type StateType = {
    isLoading: boolean;
    results: Data[];
    value: string | undefined;
}
//#enregion Types


//#region Component
const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    results: [],
    value: '',
};


export const SearchInputV2 = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState<StateType>(initialState);

    // Whenever state will be change useEffect will trigger.
    useEffect(() => {
        const getSearchResults = async () => {
            try {
                const { value } = state;
                const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/products?q=${value}`);
                setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: false, results: data }));
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        };
        // After the specified delay makes an API call
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            const { value } = state;
            if (typeof value === 'string' && value.length < 1) {
                return setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, ...initialState }));
            }
            // Makes an API call
            getSearchResults();
        }, 300);

        // This will clear Timeout when component unmont like in willComponentUnmount
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    }, [state]);

    const handleSearchChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const {target} = event;
        const val = target.value;
        setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: true, value: val }));
        console.log('Method debounce : Type value is : ', val);
    };

    const { value, results } = state;

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="search-v"/>
            <input type="text" value={value} id="search-v" name="query"
                   onChange={_.debounce(handleSearchChange, 500, { leading: true })}/>

            <div>
                {results.map((element, index) => {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
                    // @ts-ignore
                    return <p key={index}>{element.title}</p>;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );


};

//#endregion Component
```

[image: Demo of the API call]

Comment: Take a look there: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `useEffect(()=>{}, [])`. The `[]` means everytime what's inside those brackets change it will run the function inside the useEffect. In your state so eveytime a new result comes in it will run the effect, the effect get a new result everytime thus causing that infinite call. Use instead `[state.value]`. But IMO it's better to have those as separate `[value, setValue] = useState('')`, `[isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)`, `[result, setResult] = useState([])`. So you could've have `useEffect(()=>{}, [value])`

Comment: Thanks for clearing my concepts about `useEffect` `useEffect(()=>{}, [state.value])` works fine. But you are saying that I have to take those fields as a sperate state. I mean why are you saying this. Just curious?

Comment: Easier to manage, clearer code. Read that article: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usereducer-vs-usestate. 

"Anyway, I would argue once you move past managing a primitive (e.g. string, integer, boolean) but rather a complex object (e.g. with arrays and additional primitives), you may be better of using useReducer to manage this object. Perhaps a good rule of thumb:
Use useState whenever you manage a JS primitive (e.g. string, boolean, integer).
Use useReducer whenever you manage an object or array."

Answer (score 1):

Your `timer` is changing the `state` and so does the `getSearchResults`. `useEffect` will call anytime when the `state` changes. That is why, the API is being called in infinite loop. Try something like below:

```js
//#region Global imports
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';
//#endregion Global imports


//#region Types
type Data = object;

type StateType = {
    isLoading: boolean;
    results: Data[];
    value: string | undefined;
}
//#enregion Types


//#region Component
const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    results: [],
    value: '',
};


export const SearchInputV2 = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState<StateType>(initialState);


    const getSearchResults = async () => {
        try {
            const { value } = state;
            const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/products?q=${value}`);
            setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: false, results: data }));
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    const handleSearchChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const {target} = event;
        const val = target.value;
        setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: true, value: val }));

        setTimeout(() => {
            getSearchResults();
        }, 300);

        console.log('Method debounce : Type value is : ', val);
    };

    const { value, results } = state;

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="search-v"/>
            <input type="text" value={value} id="search-v" name="query"
                   onChange={_.debounce(handleSearchChange, 500, { leading: true })}/>

            <div>
                {results.map((element, index) => {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
                    // @ts-ignore
                    return <p key={index}>{element.title}</p>;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );


};

//#endregion Component
```

Comment: So using a `timer` inside `useEffect` is causing the issue?

Comment: Remove `useEffect`, make them as simple functions. This way they would trigger only when needed. When you type something, `onClick` would trigger which would fetch data after some time (you set as timeout).

Comment: both functions are causing the issue as both are manipulating `state` and at the same time would execute when `state` changes.

Comment: But In which place I reset `state` to initial when `string` value is not greater than 1?

Answer (score -1):

you cant place state as dependency, remove state and try setState instead

```
// This will clear Timeout when component unmont like in willComponentUnmount
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    }, [state]);  // here remove state and put setState or [] empty array
```

Comment: It will only call the effect once, in this example the effect must be called everytime the input has changed